# Asp.net Identity create User without HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nunit, asp.net-identity

I am trying to run some Unit Tests and I'd like to be able to create a User using the Asp.Net Identity framework but it needs an `HttpContextBase`. So, I decided to use another Stack Overflow thread suggestion and mock one up. It looks like this:

```cs
    public HttpContext FakeHttpContext
    {
        get
        {
            var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://stackoverflow/", "");
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
            var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);

            var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                    new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
                                                    HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                                    SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

            httpContext.Items["AspSession"] = typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                        null, CallingConventions.Standard,
                                        new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
                                        null)
                                .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });

            return httpContext;
        }
    }

    public HttpContextBase FakeHttpContextBase
    {
        get
        {
            return (new HttpContextWrapper(this.FakeHttpContext));
        }
    }
```

This works fine, until it gets to the Owin stuff, at which point it fails.

The Startup doesn't run for the Unit Tests. This is my Startup:

```cs
    [assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MyProject.Startup))]
    namespace MyProject
    {
        public partial class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                ConfigureAuth(app);
            }
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(DataContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<IdentityManager>(IdentityManager.Create);

            // More Identity Stuff...
        }
    }

How can I call:

    var result = await IdentityManager.Instance(this.FakeHttpContextBase).CreateAsync(user, password);
```

And get the Startup to run so I can create this User?

Or am I completely on the wrong path on this?

I am trying to run Unit Tests with NUnit in Visual Studio.

**Note:** Please don't tell me I should be using a Mock Library. Linq to Object does not work the same as Linq to Entity and I am trying to test my actual code I will be using in my application, which means testing it against an actual database. That is all working fine. This is solely about how to create a User.

Comment: Regarding your note: that you don't want to unit test but do an integration test (_"testing it against an actual database"_), does not mean you can call the latter the former and try to force it to work. I don't know where your `IdentityManager.Instance()` comes from, but the [`UserManager<TUser, TKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497520(v=vs.108).aspx) is very well usable with mocking.

Comment: Regarding your note, for the purposes of a *unit test* any differences between Linq to Object and Linq to Entity are *inconsequential*. If you are testing these differences, you are not unit testing, but *integration testing*, and that's an entirely different beast.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Great minds, eh? ;)

Comment: Despite the naming semantics, the problem remains the same :) We'll say I'm using NUnit for Integration Testing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out a different way to instantiate the User Manager with just my DataContext.

This is the final test result:

```
    private async void SeedUser()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext()) {
            var newUser = new User() { UserName = "buzzlightyear@pixar.com", Email = "buzzlightyear@pixar.com", Name = "Buzz Lightyear" };

            var userManager = new IdentityManager(new UserStore<User>(context));

            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "infinityandbeyond");

            if (!result.Succeeded) {
                Assert.Fail("Failed to set up User for TestBase.");
            }

            var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault();

            if (user == null) {
                Assert.Fail("The User was not found in the database.");
            }

            this.UserId = user.Id;
        }
    }
```